# PTIJ: How were the Na'vi able to defy the Torah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As documented by Cameron (2009) the Na'vi rose up against their foreign oppressors, expelling them from the land.

Yet it is written (D'varim 34): "לֹא-קָם נָבִיא עוֹד", "never again did/would the Na'vi arise."

So how were the Na'vi able to defy the promise written in the Torah?  I ask because I'm concerned that one breach may lead to others.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Your question contradicts Devarim 18:15 and 18:18, which say that they will arise.  Please consider editing this in...

Comment: What's Cameron?

Comment: @Yez: [The chronicler of the Na'vi uprising.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film))

Comment: And I shall crosscheck Devarim 18 shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 possibilities for the origin of the Na'vi are posed on the [Na'vi page of the Avatar Wiki](http://james-camerons-avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Na%27vi):

> From the evidence, one may conclude that the Na'vi either diverged a long time ago from the common Pandoran phylogenetic or evolutionary tree, or they may be outsiders to this world.

Hashem must have wondered about this [Chakirah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/what-is-a-hakira) (question), and in order to support the first Tzad (opinion), wrote that they arose before Moshe Rabbeinu.  According to this, "Lo Kam Na'vi" does not mean that they will not arise in war, but rather that they did not come into being as a nation after that time.

In fact, Avraham (and various other later figures in Tanach) was a Na'vi, as it says in Bereishis 20:7:

> וְעַתָּה הָשֵׁב אֵשֶׁת הָאִישׁ כִּי נָבִיא הוּא

(Additionally, they occupy such as special place in Hashem's heart that they are the reason why Techeiles is blue, as it says in Meshech Chachma Devarim 34:

> תכלית ההשגה מה שלא קם נביא
>
> Techeiles is reached because another Na'vi will not arise.
> )

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen Avatar. But, if you claim that the Na'vi expelled people from their land, then, I see no contradiction to the verse you cited.

There was no נביא (prophet) that ever expelled another nation from its land or even the land that B'nai Yisra'el occupied. That job was done by "judges" or kings, usually. The closest to a prophet doing the job that you might find is *Devorah*. However, it was mainly Barak that did the job. And, even if you were thinking that Devorah was involved, she is described as a נביאה.